# Nullable Reference Types and the Options Pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

How can we use *non-nullable reference types* in combination with the [Options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-3.0)?

Let's say we have an options model named `MyOptions`.

The services requiring those options are getting `IOptions<MyOptions> options` injected into the constructor.

Configuring the options happens on the `IServiceCollection` like this:

```
services
    .AddOptions<MyOptions>()
    .Configure(options =>
    {
        options.Name = "ABC";
    });
```

Now, the problem is in the definition of `MyOptions`:

```
public sealed class MyOptions
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

which generates the warning:

> CS8618 Non-nullable property 'Name' is uninitialized. Consider declaring the property as nullable.

1. We don't want to make `Name` nullable as then we need to place traditional null checks everywhere (which is against the purpose of *non-nullable reference types*)
2. We can't create a constructor to enforce the `MyOptions` class to be created with a non-nullable `name` value as the `Configure` method construct the options instance for us
3. We can't use the *null-forgiving operator* trick (`public string name { get; set; } = null!;`) as then we can't ensure the `Name` property is set and we can end up with a `null` in the `Name` property where this would not be expected (inside the services)

Any other option I forgot to consider?

Comment: Is `string.Empty` a viable option for your use case? I'm assuming your check for a populated value is to use `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`.

Comment: have you checked into IValidateOptions<TOptions>? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.options.ivalidateoptions-1?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Comment: You're right, we still need to validate for empty strings (or other constraints). And I just found out we can chain an additional `.Validate()` call to the options registration method which might serve our needs. Thank you.

Comment: @PatrickMcvay do you have an example on how to hook this up? Or do I just need to register the `IValidateOptions<MyOptions>` implementation as a singleton?

Comment: @huysentruitw When you configure the Option, you can pass an instance of `IValidateOptions<TOptions>` to the chained Validate method.

Comment: @JonathonChase seems like a strange usage for an interface. Probably just registering this as singleton on the `IServiceCollection` will do the trick.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I think they were trying to maintain consistency with the existing "nullable value types" feature, but IMHO that was less important a goal than having a name that was a more accurate description of what the feature actually does. :)

Comment: @huysentruitw I did some tearing apart of IServiceCollection's AddDbContext<TContext> options and found that they are using [NotNullAttribute] which is a part of JetBrains.Annotations. I am not sure if that fits your current problem, but maybe.

Comment: @PatrickMcvay seems like this is a new attribute introduced in [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.notnullattribute?view=netstandard-2.1). I'll have to check that out.

Comment: @huysentruitw the question isn't really about the pattern, it's about its initialization mechanism which is no different than any deserializer. Configuration has the same issue - both mechanisms use property-based initialization and thus generate nullability errors. *Both* of them would have to use constructor-based initialization to avoid the problem.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos correct, I've figured f.e. EF Core entities or Dapper models will suffer from the same issue.

Comment: what is wrong with using the `!` operator? you are basically saying that the property can technically be `null` but that you will know when the property is `null` and will be able to avoid using it during that time. so in that case, setting it to `null` temporarily without declaring it to be nullable in general seems like the right approach.

Comment: @DaveCousineau the problem is, by doing so, that you end up with a non-nullable reference that is null. So in places where the reference gets consumed, you will not expect it to be null.

Comment: the way I see it there are three choices: - this value will never be null at the wrong time (not nullable).  - this value might be null at the wrong time (nullable). this value might be null or notnull, but which one will be tied to the value of something else (missed by this feature). your situation sounds like one of the first two.

Comment: another way to think of it is that an exception being thrown can be ok here. if the value being null means that you used something before it was initialized, then let it throw. I often use a `MaybeThrow<T>` method to express this explicitly, which throws if the value is null and converts a nullable type to a nonnullable type.

Comment: Maybe I'm just pointing out the obvious here but how about using the builder pattern and create builders for your options, similar to how the rest of asp net core is configured? Your builders can throw if all the required fields are not set and you could opt to set the properties in a fluent manner.

Comment: We're currently setting them to `null!` in combination with using annotation attributes and the `.ValidateDataAnnotations()` extension method. I think it's the best we could do :)

Comment: @huysentruitw I think initializing to `null!` is the correct approach, if the property in question is a required one (column is not nullable). C# should add a feature where it warns you if you create an instance and don't set the properties using property initializers or even outside of property initialization in normal code flow of the same method, but until that happens, the correct notation should still be used in your code.

Answer (score 11):

It seems, that you have two possible options here. First one is to initialize an `Options` properties using empty string (instead of `null` value) to avoid `null` checks

```cs
public sealed class MyOptions
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = "";
}
```

Second one is to make all of the properties a nullable ones and decorate them using [`DisallowNull`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-attributes#specify-preconditions-allownull-and-disallownull) precondition and [`NotNull`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-attributes#specify-post-conditions-maybenull-and-notnull) postcondition.

`DisallowNull` means that nullable input argument should never be null, `NotNull` - a nullable return value will never be null. 
But these attributes only affect nullable analysis for the callers of members that are annotated with them. So, you are indicating that your property can never return `null` or be set to `null`, despite nullable declaration

```cs
public sealed class MyOptions
{
    [NotNull, DisallowNull]public string? Name { get; set; }
}
```

and the usage example

```cs
var options = new MyOptions();
options.Name = null; //warning CS8625: Cannot convert null literal to non-nullable reference type.
options.Name = "test";
```

But the next example doesn't show a warning, because nullable analysis doesn't work properly in object initializers yet, see GitHub issue [40127](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/40127) in Roslyn repository.

```cs
var options = new MyOptions { Name = null }; //no warning
```

(**Edit:** This issue was fixed already, shipped in version 16.5 in March, 2020 and should go away after updating a VS to the latest version.)

The same picture for property getter, the following sample doesn't show any warnings, because you indicated that nullable return type can't be `null`

```cs
var options = new MyOptions();
string test = options.Name.ToLower();
```

but attempting to set a `null` value and get it generates a warning (compiler is smart enough to detect such scenarios)

```cs
var options = new MyOptions() { Name = null };
string test = options.Name.ToLower(); //warning CS8602: Dereference of a possibly null reference.
```

Comment: With `NotNull` attribute it rises "CS8603: Possible null reference return".

Answer (score 5):

You should go with option 3). It does not matter whether the non-nullable atribute is null during the initialization process. What matters is the point of view of the consumer of the options instance later.

We can ensure that the options attribute will not be null by annotating it with a `[Required]` attribute and then calling `ValidateDataAnnotations()` on the options builder, such as:

```
public class MyOptions {
    [Required] public string MyRequiredText { get; set; } = null!;
    public string? MyOptionalText { get; set; };
}

services.AddOptions<MyOptions>()
    .Bind(Configuration.GetSection("MySettings"))
    .Configure(o => arbitrary configuration action here...)
    .ValidateDataAnnotations();

// When options are consumed from DI by `IOptions` or similar interfaces, 
// it is certain that MyRequiredText will not be null - in such case, exception will be thrown instead
```

When options are requested from DI and framework firstly creates the instance, it validates all attributes on properties after all registered configuration handlers are executed. If validation fails (e.g. required attribute is null or empty string), exception is thrown, which is what you should be after.

Comment: Just tried this and it works beautifully. Accidental misconfiguration is significantly reduced with this validation in place.

Answer (score 4):

If the expected behavior of the property is that it may initially contain null but should never be set to null, then try using [DisallowNullAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.disallownullattribute?view=netcore-3.0).

```cs
#nullable enable

using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;

public sealed class MyOptions
{
    [DisallowNull]
    public string? Name { get; set; }

    public static void Test()
    {
        var options = new MyOptions();
        options.Name = null; // warning
        options.Name = "Hello"; // ok
    }

    public static void Test2()
    {
        var options = new MyOptions();
        options.Name.Substring(1); // warning on dereference
    }
}
```

Comment: Additional recommended reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-attributes

Answer (score 4):

C# 11 introduced the `required` keyword modifier as another, more elegant solution to this issue. It causes a compile-time check that ensures the field or property is initialized, thus removing the warning generated by having the property as a non-nullable reference type.

Your example code would simply become:

```
public sealed class MyOptions
{
    public required string Name { get; set; }
}
```

See the following links for more detailed information:

- [MS Learn - Working with Nullable Reference Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/nullable-reference-types)
- [required modifier (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/required)
- [Required Members Feature Spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-11.0/required-members)

Comment: Options factory [uses `Activator`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/0a396acafe9a7d46bce11f4338dbb3dd0d99b1b4/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Options/src/OptionsFactory.cs#L95) under the hood, which appears not to respect `required`. So it's the same as the null forgiving operator in that it makes the compiler happy but doesn't actually verify the setter is called.